# Artifact is not published using gradle and artifactory plugin

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I'm trying to upload a simple zip to artifactory using gradle. This is my script:

```html
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def user = "$System.env.ARTIFACTORY_USER"
def pass = "$System.env.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD"

task createArchive(type: Zip){
 baseName 'myzip'
 destinationDir(new File('target'))
 from '.'
 exclude 'target'
 exclude '.gradle'
 exclude 'build.gradle'
 exclude 'README.md'
 doFirst{
  new File('target').mkdirs()
 }
}

task clean(type: Delete){
 delete 'target'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        customArtifact(MavenPublication) {
            artifact createArchive
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    publish {
        contextUrl = 'http://myrepo/artifactory'
        repository {
            repoKey = "myrepo-tools"
            username = user
            password = pass
        }
        publications ('customArtifact')
    }
}
```

The code seems to work fine but actually only the build info are published. The zip is not:

```
Deploying build descriptor to: http://myrepo/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://myrepo/artifactory/webapp/builds/myproject/1503338121156
```

My code does not seem different from the one published here: [How to build Groovy JAR w/ Gradle and publish it to in-house repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258174/how-to-build-groovy-jar-w-gradle-and-publish-it-to-in-house-repo/25260461#25260461) (which was pointed as reference in question [nothing published to artifactory using gradle artifactory plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279001/nothing-published-to-artifactory-using-gradle-artifactory-plugin)) but I'm not sure that is still valid since is quite old.

The main difference is that almost all the examples are using java plugin so they have the `from components.java` line in the publications. In my case I cannot use it as I have a custom zip.. but I can't find what else can be changed.

Thanks,
Michele.

Comment: The example you are referencing includes a "publications" list inside the "defaults" closure, which tells the Artifactory Plugin which publications should be used for the artifacs deployment. In your case it should probably be publications ('customArtifact')

Comment: Thank for the comment. I tried that but if I use the defaults I got this error: `Could not find method defaults()`. Anyway the publications is inside the `publish` configuration so I expected it to work

Comment: You were right. I was using `defaults` outside of `publish`. So that default element is mandatory (was not clear on docs https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin). Now it worked. Thanks!